# Updating feature branches using pull

Tags: git

When I'm working on a local feature branch, I prefer to rebase it to keep history clean. I have an example below of my workflow.

My branch `feature1` is local-only (no tracking set), and created off of `master`. Note that I have configured my `git pull` to rebase always.

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout feature1
git rebase master
```

The itch I have with this workflow is that it is inefficient in terms of steps. I'm working exclusively out of my `feature1` branch (I have no need to revisit `master` except to pull latest), so I just fail to see why I need to add an extra level of indirection to get latest changes from origin. So I'm wondering, is it the same if I take a few shortcuts and rebase onto my remote tracking branches instead? Here are a few ways:

```
git checkout feature1
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

Or even shorter (I can combine the fetch, and rebase into one with pull):

```
git checkout feature1
git pull origin master
```

Will all of these be valid? Are these recommended? I can't think of any shorter/more-convenient ways of doing this, so other ideas are welcome as well.

This will keep `feature1` ahead of `master` in terms of how synchronized it is with `origin`, but that's ok because I can update `master` later on when I switch to it to do some other task.

Comment: When you say this is  "a lot of work," what exactly are you saying?  A lot of steps? A lot of computation, or network traffic?  A lot of typing? A lot of room for error?  If either of the last two, consider making some git aliases to streamline the process.

Comment: @BobGilmore Seems a bit beside the point, maybe. I personally feel the workflow is a bit clunky and indirect (why can't I treat `feature1` as a `master`?). I have aliases to reduce typing but this won't reduce the number of commands AFAIK (and not without taking into consideration things like conflicts).

Comment: Just checking - you know that you can chain commands together in a git alias, right?  For example, this isn't *entirely* relevant to your example, but to grab an example from my `~/.gitconfig` file, `up  = !git fetch origin && git rebase origin/master && git submodule update` is valid.  You could possibly do something similar to combine several steps into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really think any of them is shorter than your first one.

In your first alternative way you have only fetched, so for getting the exact result than with the first one you need to merge later origin/master into local master so again 4 commands (you say you'll do it later, but you do it any way).

The second way is incomplete, I think, as you didn't rebase yet, so you would still have 3 commands.

Having said that I recommend always to do all the steps while using git. Sometimes it is tedious to have to type several commands before getting a single step but at the end you get used to it.

I wouldn't say that `git rebase origin/master` is a good practice. It is actually the same than `git rebase master` but it makes it conceptually a bit strange. You should always work locally and have the remote branches just as pointers to the different repositories you are connected with. Working locally allows you to do and undo if you did something wrong. In this case you will probably never have any error but if you get used to use the remote branches you will end up doing it for more things and probably getting problems.

If you want to save time I suggest you develop a script that runs this bunch of commands, so that you only need to run it.

Another consideration is whether to use `pull` or `fetch`+`merge`. I prefer the second for several reasons that are not the matter of this question. So again 2 commands instead of 1

Comment: The second solution does an implicit rebase because I have configured pull to do so. I also don't see the point in following a practice which is put in place simply to be one. Why should I bother updating an unrelated local branch (master) when I'm working exclusively out of my feature branch for the foreseeable future? It doesn't seem pragmatic nor efficient. Was hoping for more insight into some objective/functional reasons why local branch `master` must stay involved. Otherwise, I technically am still doing everything locally!

Answer (score 0):

First good thing is you have configured your git pull to rebase.

Assuming you are not on the branch which you want to rebase
Steps
1) git checkout feature1
2) git fetch 
3) git rebase origin/Master

Assuming you are on the branch which you want to rebase then you can avoid git checkout
Steps 
1) git fetch 
2) git rebase origin/Master

Comment: In my case, git pull will effectively handle #2 for me as well right?

Comment: Use of git pull is not recommended as original definition of git pull is git fetch + git merge. So if you have not configured git pull properly it will merge with zero warning. So as suggested by Bob you can make aliases of above commands